# Can someone explain why 100000 is given to randrange as a starting value in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm following along with the videos for Interactive Python's course on data structures and algorithms.  In one segement the following piece of code appears. It's to demonstrate a example of O(n**2) complexity.

It's supposed to loop through the range starting from 1000, and ending at 10000. But I have no idea why 100000 is given to the randrange function in the list comprehension on line 2.

Thanks in advance!

Note: i'm following along with this course - http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/BigONotation.html

```
for listSize in range(1000,10001,1000):
    alist = [randrange(100000) for x in range(listSize)]
    start =  time.time()
    print(findmin(alist))
    end = time.time()
    print("size: %d time: %f" % (listSize, end-start))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *time trial*, testing how fast `findmin()` is. That's best done with randomised data, to avoid pathological cases. The list comprehension produces the test data. The `100000` is just an upper bound for the random values in that list, high enough to ensure that even for a list with 10k integers there is a nice spread of values.

Note that it is better to use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to execute time trials.

Comment: So, to check my understanding: on the first iteration is it generating 1000 random numbers from 1-100000; then finding the smallest of those values? and on the second iteration doing the same but with a list of 2000 numbers...and so on?

Comment: Exactly. And it records how long this takes.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!